# Trigger click on input=file on asynchronous ajax done()

Tags: jquery

I have a form with some data and upload. The upload could be initiated only if data were successfully received and processed. To do that, I make an ajax call where I

1. send data,
2. check its result,
3. trigger a click() to open a file dialog box.

The last thing with click() doesn't work as it seems that **asynchronous call blocks opening an upload window**. It works only if I set `async: false`.

I cannot find anything in documentation and this site and want to know what is the problem there and how to make it working keeping the call asynchronous?

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Save",
    data: jsonText,
    dataType: "json",
    //async: false            [1]
}).done(function (msg) {    
    $("#upload").click();   
});

//$("#upload").click();       [2]
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c2v00uxn/

Note:

- if I uncomment [1] or [2], it does work (the file dialog appears as expected).
- replace click() with trigger('click') doesn't work
- replace click() with live()/on() doesn't help
- file upload control is visible as per example (so it's not because of hidden control)
- timeout settings for ajax do not help.

**UPDATE**

It's not about how to make a "click" in general, it's about how to click after an asynchronous ajax call (as of now, works only with non-asynchronous call).

Comment: @Tushar this is not the question ! sto pasting links

Comment: @Tushar I already mentioned that control is visible and that trigger() does not change anything. My question is different with one you mentioned.

Comment: weird indeed !.. I jsut tested it. it only works with async:false

Comment: Yes this is a security(?) feature of browsers. An input type file click can only be triggered from another click, and it needs to be triggered in the same scope/at the same time as the original click. I just recently struggled with this exact problem and could not find a workaround.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In JavaScript can I make a "click" event fire programmatically for a file input element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/210643/in-javascript-can-i-make-a-click-event-fire-programmatically-for-a-file-input)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829774/jquery-simulating-a-click-on-a-input-type-file-doesnt-work-in-firefox

Comment: @Bryan Downing, it's not about how to "click" in general. In my example I already do such click **and it works** but before doing it, I need an ajax call and the "click" works only when async=false. I want to know **how to click after an asynchronous ajax call**. Your links do not answer my question and please do not vote to close it.

Comment: To add to @powerbuoy, the reason it works synchronously is because the calls to `$("#upload").click();` are still in the call stack created by the user generated event (the click of the button that triggers the ajax). The ajax really has nothing to do with your problem — the done handler is firing successfully. It's essentially the same as running `$("#upload").click();` in the console.

Comment: 1) you marked my question as duplicate with a wrong answer. 2) I need a proof / documentation that describes that security (?) feature

Comment: @BryanDowning The Ajax is not *failing* (i.e., the `done` callback does run), but the fact that OP is using Ajax is very closely related to the problem (in particular in how it is different from the proposed duplicate). It seems that this question essentially reduces to "How can a trusted, user-generated click propagate its 'trusted-ness' to an asynchronous task that the click event spawns?" which is quite different from the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @BryanDowning Note further that an async `setTimeout` and `setInterval` do allow a deferred programmatic click (within a browser-defined time window), while an Ajax load callback does not allow trusted clicks, so it appears that not all asynchronous operations are equal in this regard. (http://jsfiddle.net/c2v00uxn/56/) This seems like further evidence that use of Ajax is closely related to the trusted-click problem.

Comment: @smirnov If requirement were possible, also possible to delay opening files dialog until hours after `click`, not only immediately following an asynchronous call? files "popups" could be opened - without user click - multiple times during browsing session? A mistaken "click" during an open `files` dialog initiated with `js` could result in multiple user files being mistakenly uploaded to intended, or unintended server? Could a) validate b) notify validation c) do , not do file upload stuff at `change` event ?  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/24688268/ , http://stackoverflow.com/q/23766086/

Comment: 1) I don't need delay, it wont work. 2) "mistaken click" will not result to "mistaken upload", it only opens a standard upload box (on desktop) or a photo/gallery menu (on mobile)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Its not possible right now to open a file popup window from an async ajax callback due to w3c recommended security features in the browsers.

In the file input element's activation behavior it first checks if the algorithm is **allowed to show a popup**, if not then abort the next steps without doing anything else. from [w3c.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#file-upload-state-(type=file))

**An algorithm is allowed to show a popup if any of the following conditions is true:**

1. The task in which the algorithm is running is currently processing
   an activation behavior whose **click event was trusted**.(trusted events : Events that are generated by the user agent, either as a result of user interaction, or as a direct result of changes to the DOM, are trusted by the user agent with privileges that are not afforded to events generated by script through the `DocumentEvent.createEvent("Event")` method, modified using the `Event.initEvent()` method, or dispatched via the `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()` method. The isTrusted attribute of trusted events has a value of true, while untrusted events have a isTrusted attribute value of false.
   otherwise. http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20120614/#trusted-events.)
2. The task in which the algorithm is running is currently running the
   event listener for a **trusted event** whose type is in the following
   list:

   - change
   - click
   - dblclick
   - mouseup
   - reset
   - submit
3. The task in which the algorithm is running was queued by an
   algorithm that was allowed to show a popup, and the chain of such
   algorithms started within a user-agent defined **timeframe**.

[w3c.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#allowed-to-show-a-popup)

In your code the click event is not triggered by the user but its triggered by the ajax complete callback. Here the browser declares that the event cannot be trusted to open a popup. In some browsers you can see an `isTrusted` attribute set to true if the event is declared as trusted.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted

**Note**

Different browsers trap the difference between a script activated cick and a real user using different methods.

What you can do in this scenario is to disable the file input button(or the entire form) and enable after ajax is done. That way the user wont click on the upload button until the ajax request gets completed. As of now there is no other way to do both in one click since there is a timeframe limit also for opening popup. When I checked in chrome the timeframe is 1000ms. 1000ms after the user action, window will not get opened.

Comment: Does answer intend to indicate, or provide proof through reference to documentation, that requirement _"it's about how to click after an asynchronous ajax call"_ is not possible ?

Comment: @guest271314 This helps because due to all the above conditions you cannot open a file select popup in the callback of an asynchronous ajax.. Its how browsers behave. Browsers don't want us to open a file popup from an untrusted event . So my answer is abandon hope of finding a way to do what the user what trying to do.. Even if you find something you cannot rely on that since that might be working because of security flaws.

Comment: is there any way to disable this security feature if someone want to on web page ??

Comment: I don't think so. If there is a way then that is a security flaw right? Browsers will eventually come up with patches to rectify them.

Comment: @tkay, regarding your edit "That way the user wont click on the upload button until..." My behaviour is following (I already described it to one of the answers which was deleted): it is a mobile website where user enters some data and attaches images. The upload control is hidden and I trigger a click on it programmatically. If user clicked on a "photo" button and form is not yet saved I call that ajax to validate and save data and if save went well (so I need to wait for `done()`) then I could initiate an upload box opening. If save went not ok then I show an error message and no upload box.

Comment: Okay. What about validating form inputs on their respective change events/on change event of form input just above the photo button instead of validating on the photo button click event? That way you can ensure if the user can be allowed to attach images or not before the user clicking the photo button. You can disable the photo button until the request is completed.

Comment: 1) There is one field that is currently checked right before saving the data into a database. That field is entered manually and it should be unique within the table. The application has multiple users. If user entered the value which is exist, I cancel save and show an error. No upload box should appear 2) While I do some client side validation (mandatory fields, numeric fields, etc), it's still possible that there is an error (e.g. db server is down). In this case it's still better to ensure that save went well.

Comment: The only possible method is to separate file input click from the untrusted async ajax done callback and do it before user clicking the photo button. I'm afraid there is no other way to solve this issue. I don't see any problem with using form input change events in your case. And you can check the server status using polling maybe. [A basic demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2v00uxn/69/)

Comment: 1) This is a ticketing app where user needs to enter ticket # manually (e.g. "1001"). That # must be unique within the system. A ticket will be saved only when user clicks on Save or on Upload. It can be also canceled (exit without save). I can check for unique number on `onchange()` but another user could potentially enter the same # right after that, since I do not save # in the database until Save or Upload is clicked. So, your idea could work for me only if I will "block" # for a while and do not let other users enter it.

Comment: 2) If save in db will fail, I prefer to show an error message and not an upload box.

Comment: @smirnov Thanks for explaining the difficulty clearly. I think as of now there is no way to do this in a single click event. Its clear from the docs that minimum two user clicks are required in this particular scenario.

Comment: Also, it seems it FAILS in Incognito windows on Chrome - even clicking a file input fails. At least, some of the time. That's been my experience. Can anyone verify?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery itself says that, trigger will not work for elements like file upload and anchor. (source - https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/)

> The .trigger() function cannot be used to mimic native browser events,
>   such as clicking on a file input box or an anchor tag. This is
>   because, there is no event handler attached using jQuery's event
>   system that corresponds to these events.

So in that case, you may need to create events manually using the following javascript functions.

- document.createEvent
- event.initMouseEvent
- element.dispatchEvent

A sample code + definition for the above-said functions can be found in Mozilla's developer site

https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/dispatchEvent.html

Maybe, this will help you.

Comment: Note that the `createEvent()` / `initMouseEvent()` functions are now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that works for now. It is a hack, so it may not work in the near future, as it circumvents the security features mentioned by Tkay above.

I introduce a timeout that waits for the ajax request to return the data I want to check before initiating the file browser dialog.

```
customFileUploadButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    var returnValueToCheck; //Value we want to check against

    //reference to vanilla JS ajax function that takes callback
    ajax(function(ajaxData) { 
        returnValueToCheck = ajaxData;
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        if (returnValueToCheck !== undefined) { //dummy check for example
            file.click();
        } else {
           console.log("Criteria not fulfilled");
        }
    }, 1000);//timer should be larger than AJAX timeout
});
```

To be honest, I am a bit unsure why exactly this work aside from apparently passing the browser specific tests normally prohibiting this sort of behaviour. Therefor I regard it as a hack.

My example is vanilla JS, but it should be easy to create a jQuery version. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Heenrik/tege6ox5/) for full example.

(This is my first venture into contributing, so please comment on potential errors and oversights)