# What is the JavaScript equivalent of a user clicking on the input type file button?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

What I need to do is programmatically hook into the file select dialog created when a user clicks on the button for input type file, without the user actually clicking on the button. The JavaScript would test if a file exists, and handle it as needed: read it, copy it, etc.

Comment: Could the file:// protocol be what you're looking for?

Comment: Um, you want to just click the button or try selecting a file? Selelcting the file with JS is not going to happen...

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I ultimately want JS to try and select a file autonomously -  crawl the client's file system, effectively.

Comment: @Guessed _"Yes, I ultimately want JS to try and select a file autonomously - crawl the client's file system, effectively. "_ This is not possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29873845/

Answer (score -1):

Try utilizing `onchange` event to access `File` object if user selects file ; `js` cannot select user file .

```js
var input = document.querySelector("[type=file]");

input.onchange = function() {
  console.log(this.files)
}
```

```html
<input type="file" />
```

Comment: Since in the scenario presented the user does not click and therefore does not select a file either, what would trigger the onchange?

Comment: @Guessed See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728705/trigger-click-on-input-file-on-asynchronous-ajax-done

Comment: @epascarello _"Because you did not answer the question...."_ ? See _"`js` cannot select user file"_ at post ? Similar to last sentence at comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302210/what-is-the-javascript-equivalent-of-a-user-clicking-on-the-input-type-file-butt/32302224#comment52481312_32302210 ? see also `js` included at post which could access user file , if selected by user ? , link to SO Question , accepted Answer at second comment above . Can detail why solution , explaination at post does not answer question ? How could this answer be improved ?