# Open File Dialog Not Opening

Tags: javascript, dialog

I have an input and other normal button file in my site:

```
<input type="file" id="myid_upload_background_input" onClick="testClick();"/>
```

When a button is cliked, the function below is invoked by `myid_templates_editor_open_file_dialog('myid_upload_background_input');`

```
function myid_templates_editor_open_file_dialog(elemId)
{
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
    if(elem && document.createEvent) {          
        var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
        elem.dispatchEvent(evt);            
    }   
}   

function testClick(){
    alert('Click event is invoked in an input file.');
}
```

After running the program by clicking the normal button, it displays the message `Click event is invoked in an input file.` That means the click event of the input file is successfully created, but why does the open file dialog does not open?

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do that.

Comment: @SLaks --> Why? I've done that before.

Comment: How? And on what browser & version?

Comment: @Aliyah See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728705/trigger-click-on-input-file-on-asynchronous-ajax-done

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `.click()` on `input type="file"` element within `onclick` handler of `button` element

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("upload").click()
}

function testClick() {
  console.log("Click event is invoked in an input file.");
}
```

```html
<button id="button">Click here</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="file" id="upload" onclick="testClick()" />
```