# Trigger file selection upon focusing text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So currently my site consists of a text input field, and I want a file browser to trigger as soon as I focus on it. The user then chooses a file, puts text in the textinput, then presses submit to upload.

My current HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="upload" class="card" id="upload">
<br>
<div class="enter" id="submit-upload">upload</div>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to fire the file browser up. I've tried quite a lot of ways, ranging from .click() to s, putting the textinput inside the form, and many ways of hiding the fileinput.

But I just can't seem to trigger the file input at all.

Is this a browser/security thing? Because all I can find that isn't blocked by security features is overlaying the button over the textinput, which doesn't really work in my case.

Any clue?

Comment: It is a browser security thing. Since loading file select dialog is a system-level call, you aren't allowed to invoke it through JavaScript. You could use a flash/ajax file uploader library instead, which should give you what you need (and more).

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click)

```js
$("#upload").focus(function() {
  $("#fileToUpload")[0].click()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="upload" class="card" id="upload">
<br>
<div class="enter" id="submit-upload">upload</div>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to work in Chrome, but not in Firefox... (same goes for the answer by @gaemaf)

Comment: Try substituting `click` event for `focus` event , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728705/trigger-click-on-input-file-on-asynchronous-ajax-done

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is:

In pure javascript:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('focus',function(e) {
    document.getElementById('fileToUpload').click();
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="upload" class="card" id="upload">
<br>
<div class="enter" id="submit-upload">upload</div>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

In jQuery:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#upload').on('focus', function(e) {
    $('#fileToUpload').click();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" placeholder="upload" class="card" id="upload">
<br>
<div class="enter" id="submit-upload">upload</div>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```