# Promisify HTML <a> download Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, promise, anchor

I'm using the following code to trigger a download from a href:

```
function save(href, download) {
   let element = document.createElement('a');
   element.setAttribute('href', href);
   element.setAttribute('download', download);
   element.style.display = 'none';
   document.body.appendChild(element);
   element.click();
   document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

I'd like to listen to the download-event, mainly having a promise around save(), so that I can see whether or not the user clicked on `save` or `cancel` in a (resolve, reject) promise mapping.

Any way to do this?

Comment: download also sets the path: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: I cannot listen to save/cancel browser-events, can I? The download-dialog is opened by Chrome/Firefox

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't fully get what you were doing here. Be warned `download` is not supported in IE (any version).

Comment: @Frame91 _"I'd like to listen to the download-event, mainly having a promise around save(), so that I can see whether or not the user clicked on `save` or `cancel`"_ , _"I cannot listen to save/cancel browser-events, can I?"_ No. There is not a "download-event" that am aware of.

Comment: @Frame91 See [Detect when user accepts to download a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41334881/)