# Sending file in AJAX response in spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

I am creating a file on server in a request from client-side. Now, I want to send that file in response to the AJAX response. Below is the JAVA code.

```
response.reset();
            response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Portfolio.pdf\""); 
            OutputStream output;
            try {
                output = response.getOutputStream();
                output.write(Util.readFileInBytes("/Portfolio.pdf"));
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Now, how to show a "Save As" dialog to user for saving the file. Thanks in advance for the help.
The javascript code is as below :

```
$.ajax({
            url : "export",
            dataType : 'text',
            contentType : 'application/pdf',
            success: function() { //code to display "Save As" dialog box to user.}});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876000/how-to-build-pdf-file-from-binary-string-returned-from-a-web-service-using-javas

Comment: Thanks for the help. I implemented the solution given in the above URL. But, it is creating a new window with nothing inside. The new window is blank.

Comment: _"it is creating a new window with nothing inside. The new window is blank."_  can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207106/pdf-file-upload-ajax-html , http://stackoverflow.com/a/23987178/ .

Answer (score 0):

Also see this discussion [stackoverflow.com/questions/833068/how-to-force-save-as-dialog-box-in-firefox-besides-changing-headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833068/how-to-force-save-as-dialog-box-in-firefox-besides-changing-headers).

You can encode file in **base64** string, send it to client and then assign the value to **location.href** and save dialog will be shown to user.

But it won't work in **IE**. Don't know what are your requirements.